# ввод в одну строку двух переменных, у одной из которых несколько значений

Tags: python, переменные

Мне нужно сделать ввод в одну строку двух переменных, но одна из них содержит в себе несколько значений, как я могу это сделать?

Пример: 5 1 2 3 4, где 5 это переменная N, а 1 2 3 4, переменная a.

Сейчас же у меня получается:

5

1 2 3 4

Вот код который у меня есть на данный момент

```
n=int(input())
a = map(int,input().split())
g=1
while True:
 if g not in a:
  print(g)
  break
 else:
  g=g+1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n, *a = map(int, "1 2 3 4 5".split())

print( n ) # 1
print( a ) # [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Первое значение попадет в `n`, оставшиеся соберутся в `a` в виде массива.

Comment: JS: `let [n, ...a] = "1 2 3 4 5".split(" ").map(Number);`

Answer (score 2):

например так:

```
src = list(map(int, input().split()))
first = src[0]
second = src[1:]
```

Comment: @Jack_oS, виноват, исправил :)